# Why when I dont use intermediate variable this function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

Here's my function:

```
function Ship(shipType) {

    this.name = shipType;
    this.detailedName = function() {
        var c=
            this.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
            this.name.slice(1);
        return c;
    };
}
```

Now if I try to optimize = without intermediate variable, this doesn't work.
Why?

```
function Ship(shipType) {

    this.name = shipType;
    this.detailedName = function() {
        return
            this.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
            this.name.slice(1);
    };
}
```

Here's the fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/VW5w3/

Comment: You're returning early from your function. Look up "semicolon insertion" and prepare to be chilled to the bone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi). The browser tries to correct your `return` to a `return;`.

If you put the return value into the same line as the return keyword, it will work correctly, have a look at this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VW5w3/1/

`return this.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.name.slice(1);`

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because `;` is not mandatory in JS, so `return` returns `undefined`. 
Write `return` in one line instead: `return this.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.name.slice(1);`